# Generate a API Code Documentation using python and host in web server?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

[image]

I have a Python project in folder mvc structure. I am new to Python code documentation. I want to know how can I generate the `index.html` and publish in web using app.route structure like

`localhost:9000/docs` -> I should get the project class and methods and the comments.

How can I start this for my Python project using Python libraries. I don't want to use any setups tools.

```
sphinx-apidoc - ??
```

I tried

```
 pythoncode\sphinxapidoctry\python_project\docs>sphinx-apidoc -f -A "Author" -H "Test project" -V "version 1.0" -R "release 2014" -F -d 4 -e -P -o docs pythoncode/sphinxapidoctry/python_project

 cd docs> make html
```

Then I got error like autodoc not able to import

> ```
> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'api'; the following exception was raised:
> No module named 'api'
> ```

```
  my folder structure->
     python_project->
        api=>
           endpoints->
               account.py
               tents.py
```

My account.py ->

```
def authenticateAndAuthorize(request):

"""
This function take two args

:param arg1: Some value
:param arg2: another val

:return: arg1
"""
if request.authorization:
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear, it will help you to find answer quickly.

Comment: @RedBoy, done as you said, please help me here in the error and i got html file but inside the account.py i dont have the comments wriiten in py file.attached the image for refernce

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pdoc](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc):

```
$ pdoc --http :9000 python_project
```